How long should installing Linux (Ubuntu server or Fedora server) from a USB stick onto a Dell PE R730 server take?
I have flashed an OS image onto a USB stick and put it in the internal USB port of my Dell PowerEdge rack server. The boot manager can see the drive and I can select it for a one-shot boot but when I try it, it gives me a screen.
I have created the OS image on the flash drive using balenaEtcher and inserted the drive into the internal USB port. When the server starts up, I use F11 for the boot manager and choose the internal USB drive to boot from. I select to install the OS from the options and the screen then goes blank apart from a flashing cursor and it stays like this for hours until I restart it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'm using a refurbished Dell PE R730 rack server. I'm almost completely new to this so I'm struggling a bit. I understand that it is possible to install an OS from a USB flash drive. I have created the OS image on the flash drive using balenaEtcher and inserted the drive into the internal USB port. When the server starts up, I use F11 for the boot manager and choose the internal USB drive to boot from. I select to install the OS from the options and the screen then goes blank apart from a flashing cursor and it stays like this for hours until I restart it.

"I select to install the OS from the options" - are these options generated by BalenaEtcher, or the Ubuntu/Fedora boot image, or part of the Dell firmware?

The Dell firmware

I gave up and burned a DVD with the OS and it has installed with no problems
